# Solving separable ODE with determinant

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove an energy conservation statement and I'm using Jacobi's formula which states

$$\frac{d(\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{dx_3} = \text{Tr}\,({\mathbf{H_{\omega}}})\det{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}} $$

for my setup, where

$$\mathbf{P_{\omega}} = \mathbf{P_{\omega}}(x_3) = \begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(x_3) &  \chi_2(x_3) \\  \chi_3(x_3) &  \chi_4(x_3) \end{bmatrix}
$$

with initial condition $\mathbf{P_{\omega}}(0) = \mathbf{I}$, the $2\times2$ identity matrix.
 My problem is that my RHS gives

$$\frac{d(\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{dx_3} = 2i(\eta(x_3)-\bar\eta)\det{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}}.$$

Does this simply have solution

$$\det{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}} = A\exp{2i\bigg(\int \eta(x_3)dx_3 -\bar \eta x_3\bigg)}\quad?$$

I should note that $\bar \eta$ is a constant. Any help would be appreciated - mostly on how to use my IC. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to incorporate the initial conditions

$\mathbf{P_{\omega}}(0) = \mathbf{I} \tag 1$

into the solution of

$\dfrac{d(\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{dx_3} = \text{Tr}\,({\mathbf{H_{\omega}}})\det{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}} \tag 2$

is to solve the equation in terms of *definite integrals*, into which constraints such as (1) may be readily inserted/substituted.  In the present case we have

$\text{Tr}\,(\mathbf{H_\omega}) = 2i(\eta(x_3) - \bar \eta), \tag 3$

so that (2) becomes

$\dfrac{d(\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{dx_3} = 2i(\eta(x_3) - \bar \eta) \det{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}}, \tag 4$

which in the usual manner leads us to

$\dfrac{1}{\det{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}}}\dfrac{d(\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{dx_3} = 2i(\eta(x_3) - \bar \eta), \tag 5$

that is

$\dfrac {d \ln (\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{dx_3} = 2i(\eta(x_3) - \bar \eta). \tag 6$

We may integrate this equation 'twixt $0$ and $x_3$:

$\ln \dfrac{ \mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(x_3)}{\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(0)} = \ln \left (\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(x_3) \right) - \ln \left (\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(0) \right)$
$= \displaystyle \int_0^{x_3} \dfrac {d \ln (\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}})}{ds}\; ds = \displaystyle 2i \int_0^{x_3} (\eta(s) - \bar \eta) \; ds, \tag 7$

whence

$\dfrac{ \mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(x_3)}{\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(0)} = \exp \left ( \displaystyle 2i \int_0^{x_3} (\eta(s) - \bar \eta) \; ds \right ); \tag 8$

or

$\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(x_3) = \mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(0)\displaystyle \exp \left (2i \int_0^{x_3} (\eta(s) - \bar \eta) \; ds \right ); \tag 9$

finally, we note that the initial condition (1) on $P_{\omega}(0)$ allows us to affirm that

$\det \mathbf P_{\omega}(0) = \det \mathbf I = 1; \tag{10}$

(9) thus becomes

$\mathbf{\det{P_{\omega}}}(x_3) = \displaystyle \exp \left (2i \int_0^{x_3} (\eta(s) - \bar \eta) \; ds \right ), \tag{11}$

the solution of (2) satisfying (1).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, interesting website!

Comment: Thanks for the help. May I ask what you mean by "'twixt"? I have never seen this terminology before.

Comment: @rodger_kicks:  my pleasure, sir!  "'twixt" is and English archaism/anachronism for "between"; just a product of my perhaps somewhat idiosyncratic writing style.  Thanks for checking out my website, hope you enjoyed it.  Glad I was able to help, and thanks for the "acceptance"!